# Calculate UIBezierPath Frame in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I implement a free hand drawing module using UIBezierPath, but i want to get the all frame of the curve after i finish drawing, how can i do it.

And if there a way to get the path point for a connected path, it will be great.

Comment: did you ever find an answer? I have the same question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, but if you want the bounding rectangle of a `UIBezierPath`, there is a `bounds` property.

If you want to know the position of the last point to connect another path, there is the `currentPoint` property.

If you want to examine the different parts of the path, you'll have to go down to the underlying `CGPath`, and the `CGPathApply` function.

If you want to test if a point is inside the path (would be filled), you can use the `containsPoint:` method, and if you want to test if a point is part of the path, you will have to do the math yourself using the Bézier formulas...

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. so i want to get the Frame for the path because i want to scale it. or if there any other way to do that it will be great.